# How to find n-sheeted covering space of a topological space explicitly(If exists)?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

We know that there is a one to one Galois correspondence between subgroups of the fundamental group of some topological space and covering space for a path connected and locally path connected topological space.suppose n-sheeted covering space exist for some topological space X.So if I want to construct n-sheeted covering space explicitly then what is the general way to find that?

Comment: Note that the $n$-covering might correspond to different subgroups.

Comment: yes..that's right...

Comment: Write down the universal cover. Pick the index $n$ subgroup corresponding to a specific $n$-sheeted covering space, and quotient the universal cover out by the action of this subgroup. You get the desired covering space.